# How to detect if building with address sanitizer when building with gcc 4.8?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, address-sanitizer

I'm working on a program written in C that I occasionally build with address sanitizer, basically to catch bugs. The program prints a banner in the logs when it starts up with info such as: who built it, the branch it was built on, compiler etc. I was thinking it would be nice to also spell out if the binary was built using address sanitizer. I know there's __has_feature(address_sanitizer), but that only works for clang. I tried the following simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
#if defined(__has_feature)
# if __has_feature(address_sanitizer)
    printf ("We has ASAN!\n");
# else
    printf ("We have has_feature, no ASAN!\n");
# endif
#else
    printf ("We got nothing!\n");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

When building with `gcc -Wall -g -fsanitize=address -o asan asan.c`, this yields:

```
We got nothing!
```

With `clang -Wall -g -fsanitize=address -o asan asan.c` I get:

```
We has ASAN!
```

Is there a gcc equivalent to __has_feature?

I know there are ways to check, like the huge VSZ value for programs built with address sanitizer, just wondering if there's a compile-time define or something.

Comment: Looks like there's a bug for it: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60512

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[From the GCC 4.8.0 manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html):

> ```
> __SANITIZE_ADDRESS__
> ```
>
> This macro is defined, with value 1, when `-fsanitize=address` is in use.

Comment: Thanks! One more question where RTFM helps :).

Comment: For the most current version of g++, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html -- notice that we also have `__SANITIZE_THREAD__` now.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57499943/how-to-detect-thread-sanitizer-for-gcc-5/57500218#57500218), which shows you how to determine such things for oneself, in a pickle.

Answer (score 2):

You also can go with:

```
#if __has_feature(address_sanitizer) || defined(__SANITIZE_ADDRESS__)
```

You may need to `#include <sanitizer/asan_interface.h>`.

Comment: won't work with MS compiler.