# Check whether sanitizer like AddressSanitizer is active

Tags: sanitizer

I have several versions of a project checkout out and compiled. If I spot an error, I compare the versions to narrow the problem down. Sometimes I enable sanitizers like the AddressSanitizer. If I re-use an executable, I don't remember whether it was compiled with the sanitizers or not. If the executable works fine, I am not sure whether the bug is not there or whether I did not include the sanitizer in this build. So I have to reconfigure and rebuild to make sure I have the sanitizer included.

Is there a way to check whether an executable has been compiled with a sanitizer?

Comment: You can use `ldd` on executable to check if it is linked with libasan.so. Or you can do `objdump -p` see if libasan.so is needed in dymanic sections: 
`NEEDED               libasan.so.0`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Address sanitizer can also be compiled statically with the `-static-libasan` option in GCC. Statically compiling address sanitizer is the default mode in Clang.

If you compile address sanitizer statically then it is obviously not possible to use `ldd` to verify if your binary is sanitized or not. In this case I use `nm` and check if there are sanitizer symbols in the binary:

`nm -an <executable> | grep asan`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use __has_feature(address_sanitizer), see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html (same for other sanitizers).

Comment: That would work. But I am more interested in some command line tool to extract that information.

Comment: `nm binary-name | grep '__asan\|__tsan\|__msan'`

Comment: What about for GCC? You can use: `#if defined(__SANITIZE_ADDRESS__)` as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813412/how-to-detect-if-building-with-address-sanitizer-when-building-with-gcc-4-8

Comment: It is an idea, adding a command line option to tell you whether it is compiled with sanitize or not...

Comment: And in case anyone else comes looking, for undefined behavior sanitizer it's ubsan, not usan.

Answer (score 1):

From `man ldd`:

> ldd prints the shared libraries required by each program or shared library specified on the command line.

As long as address sanitizer requires to link with libasan.so library (actual implementation of sanitizer) you can assume:

- If `ldd` won't print shared lib `libasan.so` it definitely means that address sanitizer is turned off.
- If `ldd` will print shared lib `libasan.so` it means that your linker flags includes `-lasan`, otherwise you`ll get unresolved symbol error during linking. Highly likely that address sanitizer is enabled, unless you have a bug in building system.
- Third option if you have bug in your building system. `ldd` will print `libasan.so` but address sanitizer will be turned off if you passed to linker `-lasan` , but didn't pass `-fsanitize=address`. It means that you linked your executable with address sanitizer but didn't include checks into your executable.

  Or you can do objdump -p to see if `libasan.so` is needed in dymanic sections: `NEEDED libasan.so.0`. `objdump` could give the same(and more) information as `ldd`.

Comment: It sounds like your first bullet point is wrong. If linked statically, `ldd` won't tell you anything and yet it was compiled with `libasan.a`. Finding a reference as @Perennialista mentioned is a more bullet proof idea.