# How to detect thread sanitizer for gcc 5

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, thread-sanitizer

How can I detect whether thread sanitizer has been turned on for a build using gcc 5? Neither one of the two between `__has_feature(thread_sanitizer)` nor `__SANITIZE_THREAD__` work

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    cout << __has_feature(thread_sanitizer) << endl;
    cout << __SANITIZE_THREAD__ << endl;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/t5qYme4Whyj54aYV. This compiles on the versions of clang that have thread sanitizer; but not for some gcc versions (5 in particular)

---

Both the feature check and the `__SANITIZE_THREAD__` macro are useful in detecting when the thread sanitizer has been turned on so tests can suppress false-negatives (eg. when thread sanitizer catches a bug that's not actually a data race) See [this](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerCppManual#suppressing-reports) for more

Comment: Regarding the close vote: how can I make the question clearer?

Comment: Just curious; *why* do you need this?

Comment: @JesperJuhl TSAN does not instrument some things correctly in the older gcc-based versions. Eg. inline assembly

Comment: "Detect" how? When? Why? On what?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure what you mean, isn't there just one meaning for "detecting" in this context? Similar to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test?

Comment: "TSAN does not instrument some things correctly in the older gcc-based versions" - Isn't the solution then to just use *newer* gcc versions (which may also bring other benefits)?

Comment: What I'm saying is you did not tell us what sort of outcome you want. Do you need a macro? A variable? A function call? A command-line utility? What?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I would, but some libraries that we support rely can't yet migrate to the newer versions of the compiler since the targetted client code uses the older version

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not quite sure what it means to be binary-safe in this context, but I can't really control when everyone using the library upgrades their compiler. Nor can I do it myself

Comment: `__SANITIZE_THREAD__` is only present in gcc-7+.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have to what exactly?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I see; the build model for this library is not the typical "distribute binary and include headers" one that you might be talking about (correct me if I am wrong). It gets included and built from scratch along with the client code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't even consider binary compatibility? You bought it up no? What am I missing? I just need the library code to compile and run without error on older compiler versions (which is why I need the feature check macro)

Comment: @Curious Okay, that makes sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know, but as a last resort, the following command line will find a *#define* if it exists:

```sh
diff <(gcc -dM -E -x c /dev/null) <(gcc -fsanitize=thread -dM -E -x c /dev/null)
```

On my gcc 7.4.0 it outputs:

```
> #define __SANITIZE_THREAD__ 1
```

...which means that `__SANITIZE_THREAD__` is defined to be `1` if you are using `-fsanitize=thread`, but is **not defined** if you don't.  So you should guard your code behind an `#ifdef __SANITIZE_THREAD__` rather than just using the symbol directly.

### Additional Info:

I [checked the gcc source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/ed0b0569e1f4ee44bddb565f3331b4f09a5f592b) and the `__SANITIZE_THREAD__` macro was not introduced until version 7.1.0.

Comment: It isn't a last resort, it comes not long after checking the doc. Sadly, in this case, with gcc-5, the output is empty.

Comment: Could you explain how this command works? And what it's doing? Curious :)

Comment: @Curious `-E` invokes the preprocessor and sends the output to stdout.  `-dM` displays defined macros (requires `-E` to be specified).  `-x c` forces compilation as a C file. (you could alternatively use `-x c++`) and finally `/dev/null` sets the input file to `/dev/null` (nothing).  Then it diffs this preprocessor output with and without the `-fsanitize=thread` flag.